# Rare duplicate of canvas showing up in another part of screen, without slowing performance. Android, Phonegap, JQM

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm building an app w/ JQM and Phonegap 3.1, wherein a canvas with a lot of animation and interactivity sits immediately below the JQM header. The user can make the canvas full-screen, in which case I hide the header.

I noticed early on that if I use a fixed header, then try to hide it, rather than the canvas sliding up (as it would with a non-fixed header), the top inch of the screen where the header used to be shows an exact mirror duplicate of the top inch of the canvas. Including all the animation. And it does this apparently without slowing down the app. It's just as if the canvas is being blitted twice.

Simple enough, I think, I won't used fixed headers. I haven't seen the behavior for a month. But yesterday, testing on a colleague's phone, out of nowhere I got two full-sized copies of the canvas when the page loaded, one above the other; with the top one mirroring the interactivity on the bottom one, exactly.

While I do have a spare, hidden canvas element that's used for pre-drawing sprites, there's no way it could receive a second copy of the interactive code -- and even if it did, there's no way it would be sync'd to what was going on in the first copy. So I don't think I was looking at a second canvas, I think I was looking at a very low-level redraw bug.

It wasn't reproducible. I had turned the phone horizontal at the load screen and then back at some point to vertical, the time it cropped up, but after dozens of attempts I wasn't able to make it happen again.

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior happen, and is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this really is a GPU blitting bug. It's been discussed in detail here:

[Phone Android HTML5 Hardware Acceleration - Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280195/phone-android-html5-hardware-acceleration-canvas)