# Phonegap Hardware Acceleration - 2 Canvas Objects

Tags: android, html, canvas, cordova, html5-canvas

I have an problem with my PhoneGap Application with the Hardware Acceleration from two Canvas Objects.

I need two Canvas Object to compare two different Images. On my Desktop / Handy Devices (Browser) everything is fine and the comparison works.

But when i run my compiled Android File i get an strange behaviour. When i select my first image this will be loaded in my first canvas and then when i select my second my first will be override in both canvas and only the second context from my canvas is used.

I found this Thread that the Hardware Accelartion is the Mayor Problem.

[Phone Android HTML5 Hardware Acceleration - Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280195/phone-android-html5-hardware-acceleration-canvas)

I also use for the canvas EaselJS and when i test the following code on an Android Device

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas1");
            var stage2 = new createjs.Stage("canvas2");

            var circle = new createjs.Shape();
            circle.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
            circle.x = 100;
            circle.y = 100;
            stage.addChild(circle);
            stage.update();

            var circle2 = new createjs.Shape();
            circle2.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
            circle2.x = 100;
            circle2.y = 100;
            stage2.addChild(circle);
            stage2.update();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="300">
        alternate content
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="500" height="300">
        alternate content
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the same Problem when the Hardware Acceleration is activated, i got then two Circles with an Blue Color not one with red and the other blue.

I there any kind of way to activate the Hardware Accelartion and the canvas draws or is that an PhoneGap or Android Problem with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can activate the hardware acceleration. Check this link - [Controlling hardware accelration in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling)